# Is it possible to read only a sample of data using readRDS?

Tags: r, file, sample

I have some big matrix saved using `saveRDS`:

```
# create same big matrix and save it
x = matrix(c(1:(10*10000)),10000,10)
saveRDS(x, 'test.RDS')
```

Now I would like to analyze only a sample on the data, but before taking the sample, I have been reading the full matrix:

```
# load big matrix and take a sample on the data after reading the data
x <- readRDS('test.RDS')
set.seed(1)
x[sample.int(dim(x)[1],5),]

     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
[1,] 2656 12656 22656 32656 42656 52656 62656 72656 82656 92656
[2,] 3721 13721 23721 33721 43721 53721 63721 73721 83721 93721
[3,] 5728 15728 25728 35728 45728 55728 65728 75728 85728 95728
[4,] 9080 19080 29080 39080 49080 59080 69080 79080 89080 99080
[5,] 2017 12017 22017 32017 42017 52017 62017 72017 82017 92017
```

I wonder whether it is possible to read only a sample on the data stored into an RDS file? That would mean not reading the whole matrix into memory before taking the sample, but somehow skip the data which does not belong to the sample?

I tried the following, and got the same result:

```
# find out the size of the matrix and load only the part of the matrix which is needed?
n <- dim(readRDS('test.RDS'))[1]
set.seed(1)
readRDS('test.RDS')[sample.int(dim(x)[1],5),]

     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
[1,] 2656 12656 22656 32656 42656 52656 62656 72656 82656 92656
[2,] 3721 13721 23721 33721 43721 53721 63721 73721 83721 93721
[3,] 5728 15728 25728 35728 45728 55728 65728 75728 85728 95728
[4,] 9080 19080 29080 39080 49080 59080 69080 79080 89080 99080
[5,] 2017 12017 22017 32017 42017 52017 62017 72017 82017 92017
```

How could I read a sample on RDS file without putting the full data temporarily into memory?

Alternatively, what kind of storing & loading functions one should use in order to be able to read only a sample from a file containing a matrix or data frame?

Comment: afaik that is not possible using `readRDS`

Comment: docendo's spot on. One way wld be to use a dplyr database back end, store the data there and random sample from it.

Comment: Adding to @docendodiscimus and @hrbrmstr comments, since `readRDS()` reads a "serialized" object that had previously been written to disk, R must load the entire object into RAM to do anything with it. To process the data without reading the entire object into memory it must be saved in a format that supports random / indexed access rather than sequential access.